# Is the following matrix that represents the relation on a set transitive in which would make it a partial order?

Tags: relations

I understand that this is both reflexive and anti-symmetric.  However, I don't think it's transitive.  I understand that the classic rule is aRb, bRc, aRc.  I can't seem to piece that together with this matrix.  I've been asked to draw the Hasse diagram if it is, and I feel like it's a trick question.  Is there a transitive relation that I am not seeing?  I know that transitivity can be tricky, and I feel like I'm missing something.
$$
  \begin{matrix}
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{matrix}
$$

(1,1)(1,3)
(2,2)(2,3)(3,3)(3,4)(4,1)(4,2)(4,4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

If we let your matrix be $R$, find $R^2$. If the nonzero entries in $R^2$ are in the same positions as those in $R$, then $R$ represents a transitive relation.

Comment: So multiply this matrix by itself?  R x R?

Comment: Yup! $\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: So I'm getting the result of {{1, 0, 2, 1}, {0, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 1}} that means this is not transitive.

Comment: Correct! You could also notice this from your pairs by noting that $(1,3),(3,4) \in R$ but $(1,4) \not \in R$.